# AutoFit doesn't work with wrapped text

Tags: vba, excel

I have one Chr(10) in the cell

```
cell.WrapText = False
cell.EntireRow.AutoFit ' AutoFit works
' ------------ but:
cell.WrapText = True
cell.EntireRow.AutoFit ' AutoFit works only if the cell has less then five lines.
```

If I add some characters (one line more) - AutoFit doesn't work. Text is cutted on the first and last line.
ver - famous excel 2010

Comment: It works for me till the time row height is not more than 409.5 after wrapping

Comment: @SiddharthRout, did you try on xl2010 ? What could be the reason ? I also tried on UI (Home tab - WrapText icon) - the same problem. On another comp - again the same.

Comment: One moment... explaining it with a screenshot :)

Comment: Updated the post and yes I am using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how big the data is and what is the width of the column. Reason being the max height a row can expand is to `409.5 (546 pixels)`. If you manually increase the height of the row, you will notice that after a particular height, you will not be able to increase the height of the row. Check what is that height :) Same is the concept with the width. This is applicable to both rows and columns. In case of columns the max width is `254.86 (1789 pixels)`

I used this code for demonstration purpose.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    ActiveCell.WrapText = True
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.AutoFit
    MsgBox ActiveCell.RowHeight
End Sub
```

See this screenshot

**This works**

[image]

**This doesn't**

The row has reach it's maximum. It cannot go beyond that.

[image]

The best way to handle this is to increase the width of the column.

**FOLLOWUP**

The reason why it was not working is because you had multiple columns with data in that row and you were trying to just set the WrapText of 1 cell and hence it was not working. When you have multiple columns of data you have to use `cell.EntireRow.WrapText = True` instead of `ActiveCell.WrapText = True`

Comment: Siddharth Rout, my rowsHeight is allways max 75-80. The width of the column is 45. Really thanks for your efforts. Maybe the mistake is the fact that my comp is not in India :))

Comment: LOL it has nothing to do with Geographic location. May I see your file?

Comment: Can you upload it in www.wikisend.com and share the link here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16991/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-alegro)

Answer (score 0):

A related solution in case it helps someone. I have data with 'Wrap Text' on and line breaks in cells that come from copying data from formulas that used 'Char(10)'. I need the line breaks.

For example, data in a cell should show like this:
City: New York (1950)
Country: USA

But it showed something like this:
City: New
York (1950)
Country:
USA

Selecting the column and clicking to autofit resulted in slight improvement:
City: New York
(1950)
Country: USA

Repeating manual auto-fit a 2nd time brings text to desired format.
If there is more space-separated text in a line, it takes that many more auto-fit attempts, and eventually format is fully corrected.

So in my VBA code, I replicated this and repeated auto-fit code the number of times I knew would fix my issue:

```
'Adjust column Width
        wsSched2.Columns("F:CZ").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        DoEvents
        wsSched2.Columns("F:CZ").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        DoEvents
        wsSched2.Columns("F:CZ").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

(It may work without 'DoEvents'. I haven't tried)