# Range exception while saving data in Excel in Windows C#

Tags: c#, windows, excel

Am trying to put in some data into excel cells. I get HResult rnge exception. below is the code. And also am not able to wrap the text in the cell [1,B] . am a fresher in using Office apps and not able to find a solution .

```
         myExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
                myExcelApp.Visible = true;
                myExcelWorkbooks = myExcelApp.Workbooks;
                String fileName1 = "D:\\book1.xlsx";
                myExcelWorkbook = myExcelWorkbooks.Open(fileName1, misValue,           misValue,    misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

                Excel.Worksheet myExcelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)myExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

                String cellFormulaAsString = myExcelWorksheet.get_Range("A2", misValue).Formula.ToString();

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = myExcelWorksheet.UsedRange;





                 myExcelWorksheet.Cells[1, "A"] = text;
                myExcelWorksheet.Cells[1, "B"] = commentText;
             //   myExcelWorksheet.Cells[1, "C"] = OccuranceList;

                Excel.Range r = myExcelWorksheet.get_Range("B7", "A");
                r.EntireRow.AutoFit();
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error? `Excel.Range r = myExcelWorksheet.get_Range("B7", "A");`?

Comment: Yes.The excel is opening with Text in cell A and Comment in cell B. Then i get an error here 
Excel.Range r = myExcelWorksheet.get_Range("B7", "A");
                r.EntireRow.AutoFit();

Comment: I just want to wrap text in cell[1,"B"] as the string is very large. To do this i used autofit and ended up with this error. How do i proceed with text wrap?

Comment: `r.EntireRow.AutoFit();` comes later. First you need to fix `Excel.Range r = myExcelWorksheet.get_Range("B7", "A");` See the answer that I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

> Excel.Range r = myExcelWorksheet.get_Range("B7", "A");

You are missing a row number for Cell A

Something like this?

```
Excel.Range r = myExcelWorksheet.get_Range("B7", "A1");
```

**FOLLOWUP**

> I just want to wrap text in cell[1,"B"] as the string is very large. – user1665707 59 mins ago
>
> I dont get any error now. But the text wrapping is not happening. a part of the text is not visible. – user1665707 17 mins ago

Yes, it will not autofit. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541248/autofit-doesnt-work-with-wrapped-text) for the reason.

Comment: I dont get any error now. But the text wrapping is not happening. a part of the text is not visible.

Comment: I have updated the post above. Refresh the page to see the post (See FOLLOWUP)

Comment: I want to display the entire data and not a part of it.How do i achieve this

Comment: yes. here its not working for a short text too. and am using r.EntireRow.AutoFit(); not activeCell.wraptext.There is no change happening in the width of row and column

Comment: `here its not working for a short text too.` Can you show me a screenshot?