# Autofit does size rows correctly on cells with Wrapped-Text

Tags: excel, vba

**PRELUDE: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE, There is a similar question asked [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541248/), but their solution does not work for my problem. (Their solution is applied in the code below)**

I am trying to have the height of the entire row autofit the cell with the largest block of text.

### MY CODE (snippet):

```
               With my_xl_workbook.Sheets(1).Range(rng)
                    .WrapText = True
                    .Merge
                    .value = DegreesInformationArray(j, i)
                    .Borders.LineStyle = 1
                    .Borders.Weight = 4
                    .EntireRow.AutoFit
               End With
```

### MY SPREADSHEET OUTPUT:

[image]

### WHAT I EXPECTED THE SPREADSHEET OUTPUT TO BE:

[image]

I have also, tried changing the order that the attributes are set in with no success.

Any tips, suggestions, or name calling are welcome. :)

(edit: inserted correct image)

Comment: Have you tried capturing the `RowHeight` values after each `AutoFit`?

Comment: @punts1 : No i have not tried Record Macro, this is code is being written in MS Access VBA, and is outputting an independent Excel file.

Comment: @jbarker2160 Could you please clarify why i should capture the RowHeight after calling Autofit?

Comment: @Phibins, because your AutoFit is resizing the row based on the currently used range so as you are looping through the range you are sizing the row based on the last cell in each row.

Comment: @jbarker2160 That last comment is actually the best answer ive recived! THANKS.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution:

```
Sub fitheight()
  Dim h, ma
  h = 0
  For Each c In Selection
    With c
      ma = .MergeArea.Address
      If InStr(ma, .Address) = 1 Then
        .UnMerge
        .EntireRow.AutoFit
        If .Height > h Then
          h = .Height
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Range(ma).Merge
        .RowHeight = h
      End If
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```

**How it works**

The procedure assumes you're auto-setting the height based on a selection.  It could be easily adapted to operate on a range.

It uses two variables:

- `h` to hold the maximum height
- `ma` to hold the range of each cell's merge area

It iterates through each cell in the selection, where it:

1. Loads the merge area in the `ma` variable.
2. Tests if the merged area begins with the cell's address.  Note that a Selection will iterate through merged cells more than once.  For example, if cells `C3` and `D3` were merged, Selection would iterate through both `C3` and `D3`.  We're interested in only the first merged cell, which we can do using the `Instr` test.
3. Unmerges the cell.
4. Autofits the row to the cell's height.
5. Tests the height against the `h` variable.  If greater, it sets `h` to the new height.
6. Re-merges the cell using the `ma` variable.
7. Sets the row height to `h`, which at this point is the largest height so far.

Comment: This is not very helpful without an explanation.